# Jetpack Compose rememberSwipeableState recycling issue

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a `LazyColumn` that's generating items from a list data structure, every item has a `swipeable state`. Once an item is deleted from the list (Data structure), it is also reflected in UI, a recomposition is initiated and the `LazyColumn` is updated - not showing the deleted item - Correctly.

The problem is, all the swipe state variables of the `LazyColumn` items remain as before the deletion, For example, if the list was `red`, `green`, `blue` and *green* is deleted, the swipe state of *green* which was 2nd in the list is now the swipe state of `blue` which is now second in the list. All the items shift left, but the states remain in place.

Here's the code:

```kotlin
var dailyItems= viewModel.getItems().observeAsState(initial = emptyList())

LazyColumn(...) {
   items(dailyItems) { item ->
                SomeItem(
                    item = item,
                )
            }
}
```

`SomeItem` has a `swipeable` sub component in it

```kotlin
@Composable
private fun SomeItem(
  item: Item
) {

    val swipeState = rememberSwipeableState(
        initialValue = ItemState.HIDDEN,
        confirmStateChange = {
            onActionsReveal(item.id) // Note the use if item instance
            true
        }
    )



   Box(
        Modifier.swipeable(
            state = swipeState,
            anchors = anchors,
            orientation = Orientation.Horizontal,
            enabled = true,
            reverseDirection = isRtl
        )
    ) {
      ...
    }
}
```

```kotlin
 val swipeState = rememberSwipeableState()
```

`val swipeState` is recreated when `SomeItem` is re-composed, I see a new memory address for assigned to it, I also see that `item.id` is different.

But either `confirmStateChange` is not being overridden or the previous instance of `swipeState` is referenced somehow in future invocations  - When the `confirmStateChange` is invoked - it always refers to the initial `item.id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue was solve by applying `rememberUpdatedState` to item.id

```kotlin
val id by rememberUpdatedState(item.id)

val swipeState = rememberSwipeableState(
        initialValue = ItemState.HIDDEN,
        confirmStateChange = {
            onActionsReveal(id)
            true
        }
    )
```

Comment: what is `onActionsReveal(id)`?

Comment: @nAkhmedov it's a lambda that handles the swipe state change, the point of using `rememberUpdatedState` is to make sure it gets the correct `item.id`

Comment: ok thanks, in my situation swiped state remains when i update the list with new data